# Access chrome/firefox image cache

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, caching, service-worker

Is there a way to tap into Chrome or Firefox's native cache to see what images have been stored by the browser? My app renders the same image at various different widths, and sometimes I would like to use an image at a certain width without having to make another network call to get a brand new image.

I'm aware of things such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache but these appear to be only user opt-in, meaning it requires the developer to store things that they would like to be retrieved. Is there any other way to see what is currently being stored by the browser?

Comment: No, there is not, I think that would be a major security risk

Comment: sounds like you are over thinking things somewhere

Answer (score 1):

#### No. Would you like to let others to search your temporary images folder?

What you would like to do ist already done by Browsers. If an image already cached, browsers do not make any new request from server.